# Importxml changes to data which is scraped

Tags: date, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, flatten

I had alot of help on here on [making this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGAWyJ63A8QaDqyYp140S7UQz6_4iGFQSaK3118RVQU/edit?usp=sharing) which scrapes the end date from my clients URLs so we can keep track of when the roles are closing.

The client has now changed the URL so that on the end of the closing date is also the closing time, for example 23:55 hours.
Is there a way to adjust the Importxml formula on this sheet so that it only scrapes the specific closing date and ignores anything after it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TO_DATE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IMPORTXML(B2, "//*")),
 "where lower(Col1) starts with 'closing date'"),,9^9), 
 "(\d+.. .{3,9} \d{4})"), "rd|st|th", )*1)
```

[image]

Comment: You've been an amazing help thank you so much!, do you know what this error might mean? "Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(\d+.. .{3,9} \d{4})" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "Closing Date:"."

Comment: @LuisCarlosDosSantosSousa use: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GLyI.png